# how to prepare the dataset for the purpose of training a siamese neural network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a  siamese neural network by building a face recognition model with keras. Previously I have implemented a  CNN face recognition model (with keras) by using classification so my dataset has already been split into training data,training labels, validation data, validation labels and test data. The dataset that I have used for that purpose consists of 226 image classes. I used 2799 images for training and 226 images for validation. Now I would like to use the dataset for the purpose of training a siamese neural network. How can I split the data for the purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Siamese NN, you will require a very less number of images per class. These networks learn to differentiate instead of classification. If you take a single inage from each class meaning 226 classes, then:

- Form pairs of images. If both the images in a pair belong to the same class, then the associated label is 1 else it is set to 0. So the maximum number of pairs is very huge ( 226^226 ). Limit these pairs to a certain number.

See this [blog](https://link.medium.com/F1f9FjTYZX).

Comment: What the maximum number of pairs is 225 please?